# XSL for-each-group, How to help needed

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I'm getting stuck with my XSL output to HTML.
I created a page showing Document info sorted on Relation number which need to be approved by Manager before sending to the customer, its showing type of document (and lots of other info which I removed in this queustion).

Currently I get a output in the browser

```
Relation number Document sort
    2222222     Jaarbrief
    2222222     Brief
    99999999    Jaarbrief-addendum
    99999999    Jaarbrief
    99999999    Brief
```

What I want is output like

```
Relation number Document sort
22222222    Jaarbrief
            Brief
22224325    Jaarbrief-addendum
            Jaarbrief
            Brief
33333333    Jaarbrief
            Brief
```

I'm trying already lots with XSL for-each-group but I can't get it done in a right way.

XSL Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output
     method="html"
     encoding="UTF-8"
     indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="files">
    <xsl:variable name = "count" select ="@count" />
    <xsl:variable name = "AUsr" select ="@user" />
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
       <link href="static/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link> 
        <link href="static/css/gotham.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>
        <link href="static/css/sub-style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  media="screen"></link>
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="static/css/default.js">xslthelper</script>
        <script src="static/js/cookie.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/ui.js"></script>
        <!--[if lt IE 9]>
            <script src="static/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <![endif]-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="body-content">
            <div class="wrap">   
            <br/>
                <form method="POST" id="myform" name="myform" action="PostProlo" enctype="multipart/form-data">


                        <div class="module">
                        <table width="100%" id="match_tbl" name="match_tbl">
                            <tr valign="top" align="center"> 
                                    <th width="16px"></th>
                                <th width="80px" >Relatie nummer</th>
                                <th width="70px" >Document<BR/>soort</th>
                            </tr>

                            <xsl:for-each select="folder/file[Pages[1]/Page[1]/Dummy='FACTUUR']">
                                <xsl:sort select="Pages[1]/Page[1]/Relatienummer" data-type="text" />
                                <xsl:sort select="Pages[1]/Page[1]/Type" data-type="text" order="descending"/>
                                <!-- Sortering volgorde : html table view  -->
                                <!-- All data fields to variables, also the not used fields for easy re-use : html table view  -->
                                <xsl:variable name = "file" select ="filename" />
                                <xsl:variable name = "path" select ="path" />
                                <xsl:variable name = "Count" select ="@Count" />
                                <xsl:variable name = "fileShort" select ="substring($file,1,string-length($file)-4)" />
                                <xsl:variable name = "fileShow" select ="substring($file,1,string-length($file)-20)" />
                                <xsl:variable name = "Formsoort" select ="Pages[1]/Page[1]/Duplex" />
                                <xsl:variable name = "Typedoc" select ="Pages[1]/Page[1]/Type" />
                                <xsl:variable name = "Relatienummer" select ="Pages[1]/Page[1]/Relatienummer" />
                                <xsl:variable name = "Type" select ="Pages[1]/Page[1]/Type" />
                                <xsl:variable name = "Datum" select ="Pages[1]/Page[1]/Datum" />
                                <xsl:variable name = "Tijd" select ="Pages[1]/Page[1]/Time" />
                                <xsl:variable name = "OrderNo" select ="string(format-number(position(), '00000'))" />

            <!-- html table definition starts here, with above variables used if neccesary  -->
                                    <tr valign="top" align="left"> 
                                    <td>
                                        <input id="Mname{$OrderNo}" name="Mname{$OrderNo}" type="hidden" value="{$fileShort}" />
                                        <input id="Mpath{$OrderNo}" name="Mpath{$OrderNo}" type="hidden" value="{$path}" /> 
                                        <input id="Type{$OrderNo}" name="Type{$OrderNo}" type="hidden" value="{$Type}" /> 
                                        <input id="Relatienummer{$OrderNo}" name="Relatienummer{$OrderNo}" type="hidden" value="{$Relatienummer}" /> 
                                        <input class="ng_checkbox2 refreshbox" type="checkbox" id="MID{$OrderNo}" name="MPDF{$OrderNo}"  />
                                    </td>
                                    <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="$Relatienummer" />
                                    </td>
                                <td align="center"><xsl:value-of select="$Type" />
                                    </td>

                                </tr>
                            </xsl:for-each>

                        </table>
                    </div>

                </form>
            </div>
</div>
</div>
    </body>

</html>
```

XML used

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<files user="ADMIN" D_Printer="">
    <folder>
        <file Count="1">
            <Pages Count="1">
                <Page>
                    <Dummy>FACTUUR</Dummy>
                    <Datum>28-10-2015</Datum>
                    <Tijd>10:52</Tijd>
                    <Type>Brief</Type>
                    <Gebruiker>USERX</Gebruiker>
                    <Relatienummer>2222222</Relatienummer>
                </Page>
            </Pages>
            <filename>99999999_Brief_00ZSY1Y4UEZWX81 - Copy.xml</filename>
            <path>C:\Connect\WF\Wachtrij\PPWORKDIR\UserQueues\ADMIN\</path>
            <time>2016/01/18 12:07:18</time>
            <size>891</size>
        </file>
        <file Count="1">
            <Pages Count="1">
                <Page>
                    <Dummy>FACTUUR</Dummy>
                    <Datum>28-10-2015</Datum>
                    <Tijd>10:52</Tijd>
                    <Type>Brief</Type>
                    <Gebruiker>USERX</Gebruiker>
                    <Relatienummer>99999999</Relatienummer>
                </Page>
            </Pages>
            <filename>99999999_Brief_00ZSY1Y4UEZWX81.xml</filename>
            <path>C:\Connect\WF\Wachtrij\PPWORKDIR\UserQueues\ADMIN\</path>
            <time>2016/01/18 12:06:10</time>
            <size>892</size>
        </file>
        <file Count="1">
            <Pages Count="1">
                <Page>
                    <Dummy>FACTUUR</Dummy>
                    <Datum>28-10-2015</Datum>
                    <Tijd>10:52</Tijd>
                    <Type>Jaarbrief</Type>
                    <Gebruiker>USERX</Gebruiker>
                    <Relatienummer>2222222</Relatienummer>
                </Page>
            </Pages>
            <filename>99999999_Brief_00ZSY1YU093NZF2 - Copy - Copy.xml</filename>
            <path>C:\Connect\WF\Wachtrij\PPWORKDIR\UserQueues\ADMIN\</path>
            <time>2016/01/18 12:07:34</time>
            <size>899</size>
        </file>
        <file Count="1">
            <Pages Count="1">
                <Page>
                    <Dummy>FACTUUR</Dummy>
                    <Datum>28-10-2015</Datum>
                    <Tijd>10:52</Tijd>
                    <Type>Jaarbrief</Type>
                    <Gebruiker>USERX</Gebruiker>
                    <Relatienummer>99999999</Relatienummer>
                </Page>
            </Pages>
            <filename>99999999_Brief_00ZSY1YU093NZF2 - Copy.xml</filename>
            <path>C:\Connect\WF\Wachtrij\PPWORKDIR\UserQueues\ADMIN\</path>
            <time>2016/01/18 12:06:46</time>
            <size>900</size>
        </file>
        <file Count="1">
            <Pages Count="1">
                <Page>
                    <Dummy>FACTUUR</Dummy>
                    <Datum>28-10-2015</Datum>
                    <Tijd>10:52</Tijd>
                    <Type>Jaarbrief-addendum</Type>
                    <Gebruiker>USERX</Gebruiker>
                    <Relatienummer>99999999</Relatienummer>
                </Page>
            </Pages>
            <filename>99999999_Brief_00ZSY1YU093NZF2.xml</filename>
            <path>C:\Connect\WF\Wachtrij\PPWORKDIR\UserQueues\ADMIN\</path>
            <time>2015/12/03 16:40:46</time>
            <size>909</size>
        </file>
        <file>
            <filename>dummy.xml</filename>
            <path>C:\UserQueues\ADMIN\</path>
            <time>2016/01/18 12:14:32</time>
            <size>445</size>
        </file>
    </folder>
</files>
```

I hope you can help me, and let me know if I miss any needed info.
Very big Thanks in advance

Comment: Please edit your question and fix all the `<br>` elements you have inserted. Indent code (and the expected output, too) by four spaces instead of using `<br>`.

Comment: Changed the layout, removed the BR elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are grouping `file` elements by the `Relatienummer` specified in the first page, so the `xsl:for-each-group` would look like this

You then need to iterate over the elements in the current group, so you can output the rows

```
<xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
```

Then you can just check if it is the first row in the group to decide whether to output the number

```
<xsl:if test="position() = 1">
    <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
</xsl:if>
```

Try this simplified XSLT as your starting point

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />

 <xsl:template match="files">
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Relation number</th>
            <th>Document sort</th>
        </tr>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="folder/file" group-by="Pages/Page[1]/Relatienummer">
            <xsl:for-each select="current-group()">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:if test="position() = 1">
                            <xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()" />
                        </xsl:if>    
                    </td>
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="Pages/Page[1]/Type" /></td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
        </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this one out tonight, and let you know the results.

Comment: Works great :) Now I will build rest of the page based on this,
I hope the Approve button logic works :)

Comment: I got a question, 
If I put a checkbox at Value-of Select="current-grouping-key wil it select all documents or only one, 

In my result I get only 1 document when posting the form.
Maybe this is as designed

Comment: That is not really an XSLT issue, but how you want you website to work. If you just want a checkbox per "key", it is up to you to get all the documents for that key on the server, when the form is posted back. All that gets posted back with a checkbox is the name of the check box, and the value.

Comment: thanks Tim, I will build some Jquery to make this work on the site